# How can I check if an int is a legit HttpStatusCode in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration, http-status-codes

I wish to make sure that the number a person provides, is a legit [HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx).

At first I thought of using `Enum.TryParse(..)` or `Enum.Parse(..)` but it's possible I get an invalid result with some bad data provided..

eg.

```
In: Enum.Parse(typeof (HttpStatusCode), "1")
Out: 1

In: Enum.Parse(typeof (HttpStatusCode), "400")
Out: BadRequest

In: Enum.Parse(typeof (HttpStatusCode), "aaa")
Out: System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'aaa' was not found.
```

Ok, so if I pass in a bad *aaa* value, I get the System.Argument exception. But when I pass in a number 1 (as text, not an int) i get the return value of 1. I would have expected this to fail and throw an exception.

Passing a value of 400 *does* return the correct `BadRequest` enumeration.

Any ideas, folks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse the value simply us the IsDefined method

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(HttpStatusCode),value)
```

The reason why the case with "1" doesn't fail is that you can do binary arithmetic on enumerations. This is used a lot for flags, thus values not specifically in the enum might still be valid values

Comment: Sir/Lady, you are a Gentleman/Gentlewoman and a Scholar! /me whispers Woot^Woot!

Answer (score 5):

That *is* the [documented behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx):

> If *value* is a name that does not correspond to a named constant of *enumType*, the method throws an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx). If *value* is the string representation of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the *enumType* enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is *value* converted to an integral type. If this behavior is undesirable, call the [IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) method to ensure that a particular string representation of an integer is actually a member of *enumType*.

Comment: Well found. I did skim through the docs at lightspeed and missed this *very* important paragraph. Well spotted!